# has_one :through without join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a Rails project that implements numerous engines that are isolated.

1. Primary Engine (always there)
2. Extension Engine #1 (optional plugin that extends Primary Engine)
3. Extension Engine #2 (optional plugin that extends Primary Engine)
4. Etc.

Long-story-short, I need to have the **extension engines** to add models with relationships to the **primary engine's** models.

The extensions SHOULD NOT MODIFY any other engine's physical tables, however theres no reason the extensions couldn't create their own tables that act as join tables to reference the primary engine's tables.

For the sake of simplicity, below illustrates what I'm looking to do.

### Primary Engine

#### .../app/models/models/user.rb

```
module PrimaryEngine
    User < ActiveRecord::Base
    End
end
```

### Vehicle Engine

```
# .../vendor/engines/vehicle_engine/app/models/vehicle.rb
module VehicleEngine
    Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
    End
end

# .../vendor/engines/vehicle_engine/config/initializers/user_extension.rb
...
PrimaryEngine::User.class_eval do 
    has_one :vehicle, :through => :vehicle_engine_users_vehicles
end
...
```

The only reason why I need to use a join table is because I cannot (should not) modify **primary engine's** `primary_engine_user` table. Typically you would just add a new column to the `primary_engine_user` table, i.e. `primary_engine_user.vehicle_id`.

The things is, I dont want to have to create a model for the `:through =>` part because there is nothing in that join table that I would need to expose functionality to.

```
CREATE TABLE vehicle_engine_users_vehicles
(
  primary_engine_user_id integer NOT NULL,
  vehicle_id integer NOT NULL
)
```

I am wondering if there is a way to get `has_one` to work like the `has_and_belongs_to_many`, where the join table is inferred but does not need to be specified?

Thanks!

### Clarification update:

A `PrimaryEngine::User` can have 1 vehicle, but `VehicleEngine::Vehicle` can have many different users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what I think you are asking is not that the through be inferred, (since has_and_belongs_to_many infers the through) but rather that the linking table be used without the model.

I don't think so.  When the :through option is used, ActiveRecord goes to the association named in the :through, then goes to the model for that association (so both the through association and the through model need to exist).

Go ahead and create the empty model.  It doesn't cause much of a problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if there is a way to get has_one to work like the has_and_belongs_to_many, where the join table is inferred but does not need to be specified?

You may not need a join table if you have a one-to-one relationship, because you could do that by just having a foreign key in either table. But, you said you couldn't do a foreign key.

If you know you will need to switch to one-to-many or many-to-many later, then you'd likely use a fully-fledged join model that has an id column. (The general rule is that HABTM is for join tables that only have two columns- the two foreign keys to the tables to join, and otherwise the join table is going to be a model and you can either do a has_many through that model, etc. as needed.) This is what @Marlin_Pierce said.

To make has_one act like a singular HABTM, you'd be overriding its default behavior which would be confusing to others. Don't do it.

So, I'd suggest just adding additional methods to the model to make it act a little more like a has_one:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :vehicles

def vehicle
  vehicles.first
end

def vehicle=(vehicle)
  vehicles = vehicle ? [vehicle] : []
end
```

HABTM and has_many always return an empty array if the relationship is valid even if no rows are returned, so you don't need to do a `try` or check for nil in the getter.

But, thinking more on this, I think really what you want is `has_one :vehicle, through: :vehicle_engine_users_vehicle`. That requires a join model, but is the "rails way" to do what you are looking to do, and is described [here in the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_one-through-association). Then, if you were writing a gem to do this, to make it easier if needed, you could write generator(s) to create the join model and related migration(s).

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for the comment. Unfortunately I **cannot** modify the parent table, only my engine's own tables. This means that I cannot put a `vehicle_id` on the `primary_engine_user` table.

Comment: @Ryan_Griffith understood. Others will come to this answer and want to make sure I leave that option open for them. For you, I'd suggest just adding a method on the model to get `.first` on the result set from HABTM, if you are sure you don't need a join model.